# SteamCMD dedicated CS:GO server can't connect

Tags: steam, technical-issues, counter-strike-global-offensive, steamcmd

I'm trying to host a CS:GO server, but I can't get it to work.
The ports are open from 27000-27030, as well as 4380.

When I host it, I can see it under Lan in the server browser.
But if I view the server properties it has my local IP and not my public IP, and I am guessing this is why it's not working.

I can connect to the local IP but how do I make it so the IP of the server becomes my public IP allowing for people to connect?

Because in my router the traffic on these ports are being redirected to my local IP, but in CS:GO the IP of the server is my local ip 192.x.x.x and not the public 90.x.x.x.

What can I do?

```
Set SteamNetworkingSockets P2P_STUN_ServerList to "1.1.1.1" 

Gameserver logged on to Steam, assigned identity

Logging into Steam gameserver account with logon token
```

I get these messages, so I assume most of the things are correctly formatted.

Comment: what is sv_lan set to? [This thread](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/13/828937546117038532/) has a few suggestions

Comment: I've had past issues hitting my external address from the inside of my network; have you tried connecting from a remote host?